# How do i change the behavior of **clear** on CentOS7 such that it will NOT clear scrollback buffers on xterm?

Tags: linux, putty, centos-7, mobaxterm, ncurses

I have a VM running **CentOs 7.2.1511**. It includes **ncurses 5.9**.
I use both MobaXterm and PuTTY.

Whenever I run the **clear** command, the scrollback buffers are cleared automatically as well.

This behavior is not observed in ncurses 5.7 (on another CentOs VM CentOS release 6.5 (Final)).

Reading ncurses changelog, a change was made so that ncurses takes into account "the E3 extended capability to clear the terminal's scrollback buffer"

The man page also mentions terminfo:

> It looks in the environment for the terminal type and then in the **terminfo database** to figure out how to clear the screen.

So **terminfo** has data that **clear** uses to determine whether it should clear the terminal's scrollback buffer. I found a utility, **infocmp**, that can print out terminfo descriptions.

**infocmp**

> NAME
>
> ```
>    infocmp - compare or print out terminfo descriptions
> ```

I have placed the output below under details.

The "clear" entry in terminfo shows this "clear=\E[H\E[2J,".

When I run **strace clear** on the **CentOS7** VM I see this (full strace is below, under details)

```
write(1, "\33[3;J\33[H\33[2J", 12
)      = 12
```

When I run **strace clear** on the **CentOS6.5** VM I see this

```
write(1, "\33[H\33[2J", 7
)
```

I think the new version of **clear** is picking up something from somewhere that's telling it to prepend "**\33[3;J**". (That is probably the change the changelog talks about)

But as the man page stated; that information is gathered from **terminfo**. My terminfo clear entry does not have **\33[3;J\33[H\33[2J**; rather it has **\33[H\33[2J**.

So; if I am missing something and this is not a bug in ncurses 5.9;

How do I change the behavior of **clear** on Centos7 to NOT clear the scrollback buffer?

I am not looking at modifying the code and compile, nor replace 5.9 with 5.7.

Thank you all

---

### **Details**:

O/S: CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
ncurses: ncurses version 5.9 (patch 20130511) [retrieved from 'man clear']

### **Output of infocmp on CentOS 7**:

```
# infocmp
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm
xterm|xterm terminal emulator (X Window System),
        am, bce, km, mc5i, mir, msgr, npc, xenl,
        colors#8, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, pairs#64,
        acsc=``aaffggiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
        bel=^G, blink=\E[5m, bold=\E[1m, cbt=\E[Z, civis=\E[?25l,
        clear=\E[H\E[2J, cnorm=\E[?12l\E[?25h, cr=^M,
        csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=^H,
        cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=^J, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C,
        cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\E[A,
        cvvis=\E[?12;25h, dch=\E[%p1%dP, dch1=\E[P, dl=\E[%p1%dM,
        dl1=\E[M, ech=\E[%p1%dX, ed=\E[J, el=\E[K, el1=\E[1K,
        flash=\E[?5h$<100/>\E[?5l, home=\E[H, hpa=\E[%i%p1%dG,
        ht=^I, hts=\EH, ich=\E[%p1%d@, il=\E[%p1%dL, il1=\E[L,
        ind=^J, indn=\E[%p1%dS, invis=\E[8m,
        is2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>, kDC=\E[3;2~, kEND=\E[1;2F,
        kHOM=\E[1;2H, kIC=\E[2;2~, kLFT=\E[1;2D, kNXT=\E[6;2~,
        kPRV=\E[5;2~, kRIT=\E[1;2C, kb2=\EOE, kbs=\177, kcbt=\E[Z,
        kcub1=\EOD, kcud1=\EOB, kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA,
        kdch1=\E[3~, kend=\EOF, kent=\EOM, kf1=\EOP, kf10=\E[21~,
        kf11=\E[23~, kf12=\E[24~, kf13=\E[1;2P, kf14=\E[1;2Q,
        kf15=\E[1;2R, kf16=\E[1;2S, kf17=\E[15;2~, kf18=\E[17;2~,
        kf19=\E[18;2~, kf2=\EOQ, kf20=\E[19;2~, kf21=\E[20;2~,
        kf22=\E[21;2~, kf23=\E[23;2~, kf24=\E[24;2~,
        kf25=\E[1;5P, kf26=\E[1;5Q, kf27=\E[1;5R, kf28=\E[1;5S,
        kf29=\E[15;5~, kf3=\EOR, kf30=\E[17;5~, kf31=\E[18;5~,
        kf32=\E[19;5~, kf33=\E[20;5~, kf34=\E[21;5~,
        kf35=\E[23;5~, kf36=\E[24;5~, kf37=\E[1;6P, kf38=\E[1;6Q,
        kf39=\E[1;6R, kf4=\EOS, kf40=\E[1;6S, kf41=\E[15;6~,
        kf42=\E[17;6~, kf43=\E[18;6~, kf44=\E[19;6~,
        kf45=\E[20;6~, kf46=\E[21;6~, kf47=\E[23;6~,
        kf48=\E[24;6~, kf49=\E[1;3P, kf5=\E[15~, kf50=\E[1;3Q,
        kf51=\E[1;3R, kf52=\E[1;3S, kf53=\E[15;3~, kf54=\E[17;3~,
        kf55=\E[18;3~, kf56=\E[19;3~, kf57=\E[20;3~,
        kf58=\E[21;3~, kf59=\E[23;3~, kf6=\E[17~, kf60=\E[24;3~,
        kf61=\E[1;4P, kf62=\E[1;4Q, kf63=\E[1;4R, kf7=\E[18~,
        kf8=\E[19~, kf9=\E[20~, khome=\EOH, kich1=\E[2~,
        kind=\E[1;2B, kmous=\E[M, knp=\E[6~, kpp=\E[5~,
        kri=\E[1;2A, mc0=\E[i, mc4=\E[4i, mc5=\E[5i, meml=\El,
        memu=\Em, op=\E[39;49m, rc=\E8, rev=\E[7m, ri=\EM,
        rin=\E[%p1%dT, rmacs=\E(B, rmam=\E[?7l, rmcup=\E[?1049l,
        rmir=\E[4l, rmkx=\E[?1l\E>, rmm=\E[?1034l, rmso=\E[27m,
        rmul=\E[24m, rs1=\Ec, rs2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>, sc=\E7,
        setab=\E[4%p1%dm, setaf=\E[3%p1%dm,
        setb=\E[4%?%p1%{1}%=%t4%e%p1%{3}%=%t6%e%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%{6}%=%t3%e%p1%d%;m,
        setf=\E[3%?%p1%{1}%=%t4%e%p1%{3}%=%t6%e%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%{6}%=%t3%e%p1%d%;m,
        sgr=%?%p9%t\E(0%e\E(B%;\E[0%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p7%t;8%;m,
        sgr0=\E(B\E[m, smacs=\E(0, smam=\E[?7h, smcup=\E[?1049h,
        smir=\E[4h, smkx=\E[?1h\E=, smm=\E[?1034h, smso=\E[7m,
        smul=\E[4m, tbc=\E[3g, u6=\E[%i%d;%dR, u7=\E[6n,
        u8=\E[?1;2c, u9=\E[c, vpa=\E[%i%p1%dd,
```

### strace clear: (CentOS7)

```
# strace clear
execve("/bin/clear", ["clear"], [/* 36 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xf60000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd26198c000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=41031, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 41031, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd261975000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@\316\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=174520, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2268928, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd261535000
mprotect(0x7fd26155a000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fd26175a000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7fd261750
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2107816, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3932736, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd26116d000
mprotect(0x7fd261323000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fd261523000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b6000) = 0x7fd26150
mmap(0x7fd261529000, 16960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd261529000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd26198b000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd261989000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fd261989740) = 0
mprotect(0x7fd261523000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fd26175a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x600000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fd261986000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fd261975000, 41031)           = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) =0
brk(0)                                  = 0xf60000
brk(0xf81000)                           = 0xf81000
brk(0)                                  = 0xf81000
stat("/root/.terminfo", 0xf601c0)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/terminfo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=6, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/terminfo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
access("/etc/terminfo/x/xterm", R_OK)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm", R_OK) = 0
open("/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3371, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd261985000
read(3, "\32\0010\0&\0\17\0\235\1l\5xterm|xterm terminal"..., 4096) = 3371
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fd261985000, 4096)            = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) =0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) =0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=62, ws_col=112, ws_xpixel=896, ws_ypixel=930}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd261985000
write(1, "\33[3;J\33[H\33[2J", 12
)      = 12
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place to look is in the *extended* capabilities, shown using the `-x` option of `infocmp`, e.g.,

```
infocmp -1x |grep E3
```

would show

```
    E3=\E[3J,
```

(I used the `-1` option to format the output as a single column).  You can as usual do

```
infocmp -x  >foo
vi foo # remove/adjust whatever
sudo tic -x foo
```

Both `xterm` and `linux` (Linux console) support this feature.

Further reading:

- [Miscellaneous extensions](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_Miscellaneous_extensions_)

Comment: Thank you very much! I edited the file and changed `E3=\E[3J,` to `E3=,`. However I had to remove `linux` from the `infocmp` arguments as the output didn't include `E3`.